# Store primary key from db2 merge statement in Php script

Tags: php, db2

I have a php script where I have set parameters that I'm then using in 2 merge statements for db2.

The issue is that on my first merge statement I need to grab and use the primary key of the affected row (if the merge did an update, grab the ID of the updated row. If it did an insert grab the newly created ID) because I need to use the ID /primary key in the 2nd merge (either insert or update the row that has it already)

My two merge statements:

```
/*products table*/
MERGE INTO products AS P
    USING(VALUES(

        :GROUP,
        :DTL12,
        :DTL13,
        :CUSTNM,
        :SELLINGN,
        :COUNT_PLMN_1,
        :LAST_DATE

        )
    )

AS S(GROUP,DTL12,DTL13,CUSTNM,SELLINGN,COUNT_PLMN_1,LAST_DATE)
ON s.GROUP = p.GROUP and s.DTL12 = p.DTL12 and s.DTL13 = p.DTL13 and s.CUSTNM = p.CUSTNM 

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET LAST_DATE = s.LAST_DATE

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.GROUP,s.DTL12,s.DTL13,s.CUSTNM,s.SELLINGN,s.COUNT_PLMN_1,s.LAST_DATE)



/*ORDERS Table*/
MERGE INTO ORDERS AS PO
    USING(VALUES(

        /*need foreign key, which is id from products table*/
        :QUANTITY,
        :LAST_DATE,
        :INVOICE_NUMBER
    ))

AS S(PRODUCT_ID,quantity_ordered,LAST_DATE,invoice_number)
ON s.PRODUCT_ID = po.id

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET LAST_DATE = s.LAST_DATE, quantity_ordered = s.quantity_ordered, invoice_number = s.invoice_number

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.PRODUCT_ID, s.quantity_ordered, s.LAST_DATE, s.invoice_number)
```

How can I properly handle this within a php script?

Comment: `GROUP, DTL12, DTL13, CUSTNM` - is this the unique key in the `Products` table? If not, then what's the logic with the `Orders` table, if the 1-st merge updates multiple rows on given input values?

Comment: Good question, there is only one row in the products table for that unique combo so either one row isil inserted or updated but this also happens in a while loop so for each row result it does the product merge tl either create or update a single row

Comment: @MarkBarinstein to clear up confusion: those four columns/values are what make each row unique but they also have an ID column as a PK. But in the loop each merge would be done one at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to do `select` from `merge` in db2 for luw. To get an affected id (inserted or updated) in `Product` you can use the following query:

```
with s (GROUP, DTL12, DTL13, CUSTNM, SELLINGN, COUNT_PLMN_1, LAST_DATE) as (VALUES
  (:GROUP, :DTL12, :DTL13, :CUSTNM, :SELLINGN, :COUNT_PLMN_1, :LAST_DATE)
) 
, u as (
select id 
from new table (
update products p
set (last_date)=(
select s.last_date 
from s
where s.GROUP = p.GROUP and s.DTL12 = p.DTL12 and s.DTL13 = p.DTL13 and s.CUSTNM = p.CUSTNM
)
where exists (
select s.last_date 
from s
where s.GROUP = p.GROUP and s.DTL12 = p.DTL12 and s.DTL13 = p.DTL13 and s.CUSTNM = p.CUSTNM
)
)
)
, i as (
select id
from new table(
insert into products (GROUP, DTL12, DTL13, CUSTNM, SELLINGN, COUNT_PLMN_1, LAST_DATE)
select GROUP, DTL12, DTL13, CUSTNM, SELLINGN, COUNT_PLMN_1, LAST_DATE
from s
where not exists (
select 1
from products p
where s.GROUP = p.GROUP and s.DTL12 = p.DTL12 and s.DTL13 = p.DTL13 and s.CUSTNM = p.CUSTNM
)
)
)
select id 
from table (values coalesce((select id from u), (select id from i))) t(id);
```

Here are 2 data-change statements against `Products` - `Update` (if the corresponding row exists) and `Insert` (if the corresponding row doesn't exist). `Select` from both data-change statements retrieves `ID` affected (generated upon `Insert` or updated), and one of them is returned.